# Insert data into Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I have data (network packets) to be inserted in a **Cassandra** database!

Unfortunately, my application needs at about 1min to insert 10000 packets!

I'm looking for if there is anyone who can help me to operate the java multithreading concept to **accelerate** the insertion! Here is my code:

```
PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler;
jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {
    GestionPacketDAO g1;
    int row=0;

    public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {
        row++;

        String s = packet.toHexdump();

        try {
            g1 = new GestionPacketDAO();                 
            g1.Insert(s, row);// Insert is the function which inserts data into  database
        } 
        catch (InvalidRequestException exg) {
            Logger.getLogger(AccueilInsertion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exg); 
        } 
        catch (TException exg) {
            Logger.getLogger(AccueilInsertion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exg);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is:

- Use a ThreadPoolExecutor with maybe 10 threads.
- Use a client library that does connection pooling (e.g. Astyanax or the DataStax CQL3 java driver). Ensure there are at least as many connections as threads.
- Back the ThreadPoolExecutor by a queue of fixed size (e.g. ArrayBlockingQueue)
- The producer, in your case the nextPacket function, calls ThreadPoolExecutor.execute, which adds a Runnable to the queue. You need to handle when your queue is full appropriately by handling RejectedExecutionException. You can sleep and block reading your packets or drop the packet or some alternative.

An alternative is to have multiple threads running your packet handler if that is possible.  Each one can have its own Cassandra connection and write directly.  That will be more efficient if you can do it.